# Java garbage collector

Tags: java

How does Java garbage collector work and which algorithm is best which Java garbage collector use.Morevoer,
In Java memory leaks happen or not?

Comment: Try these http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=How+does+Java+garbage+collector+work+and+which+algorithm+is+best+which+Java+garbage+collector 1 million results. http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=In+Java+memory+leaks+happen+or+not 2 million results.

Answer (score 2):

> How does Java garbage collector work
>   and which algorithm is best which Java
>   garbage collector use.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-136373.html

> Morevoer, In Java memory leaks happen
>   or not?

Yes, memory leaks can happen:

http://olex.openlogic.com/wazi/2009/how-to-fix-memory-leaks-in-java/

Comment: you might want to clarify how "memory leaks" in java compare to "memory leaks" in languages like C.  java does not have the "lost forever and never to be regained" leaks like C, only the "holding on to stuff you don't really need" kind.

Comment: @jtahlborn - not worth the effort for a "not a real question".